# How to make the modules conforming to the OCaml signatures

Tags: ocaml

I am making a turtle graphics program by using ocaml. And this requires to provide an implementation of the module conforming to the following OCaml signature.

```
type program
type ins

val mf: float -> ins
val mb: float -> ins
val tl: float -> ins
val tr: float -> ins
val pu: ins
val pd: ins
val repeat: int -> program -> ins
val make_program: ins list -> program

type stroke
val strokes: program -> stroke list

type state
val animate: program -> state list

val strokes': program -> unit
val animate': program -> unit
```

- Define a type for turtle programs and for turtle instructions.
- The mf, mb, tl, tr, pu, pd, repeat and make_program functions are
  used to build instructions and programs.
- Define a type for strokes.
- Program a function strokes that, given a turtle program, returns the
  list of the strokes drawn by the turtle.
- Define a type for the state of the turtle.
- Program a function animate that, given a turtle program, returns the
  list of states of the turtle.
- The strokes' and animate' render the strokes and turtle animation

This is my code for `mf`, `pu` and `pd`:

```
type turtle = {
    mutable x : float;
    mutable y : float;
    mutable phi : float;
    mutable stt : int;
}

let round = int_of_float

let pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

let rad_of_deg a = a *. pi /. 180.

let p = { x = 100.; y = 100.; phi = 0.; stt = 1 }

let pu() =
    p.stt <- 0

let pd() =
    p.stt <- 1

let mf l = 
        let x2 = (p.x) +. l *. cos (rad_of_deg p.phi)
        and y2 = (p.y) +. l *. sin (rad_of_deg p.phi) in
        moveto (round p.x) (round p.y);
        if (p.stt == 1) then lineto (round x2) (round y2);
        p.x <- x2;
        p.y <- y2
```

The output of `mf` is:
`val mf: float -> unit = <fun>`

My question is how to make it look like the requirements?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to build the modules that conform the above Ocaml signatures

Comment: From what I see your problem is that your function `mf` returns `unit` and you want it to return `ins`. But, what type is `ins`? It's an abstract type, which means you are going to specify what it is in your implementation, but not reveal it in your module interface. So, you need to put in some work before you get to the questions that SO can help with.

Comment: Show us your code and tell us what the signature is supposed to mean (in particular what the type `ins` represents).

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a few hints, but you should consider to learn OCaml textbooks. I'm not going to teach you OCaml in a few keystrokes, not because I don't want to, but because it is impossible.

In OCaml a compilation unit consists of two parts:

- module implementation
- module signature

Module implementation consists of values and types, and each value has a type, associated with it. OCaml will infer types for values for you, but you can help it, using type annotations.

The implementation should be put in a file that has extension `.ml`. Signature should be put in a file with `.mli` extension. OCaml compiler will take them both, if they share the same name and build a compilation unit for you, that can be later linked into an executable.

For example you can put the given above signature into the file named `gr.mli`. Then you need to write a file that will implement this interface. You must name this file `gr.ml` and put your types and values into it. Then you can compile it using

```
ocamlbuild gr.cmo
```

and OCaml compiler will check whether your implementation actually implements the given signature. In order to conform to the signature, your module should contain all the values and types, specified in the signature and their types should be the same. Indeed, your implementation can contain more values, and types of values can be more general, than what is specified in a signature, but we're going to far away.

What you're showing in your example, (I'm refering to `val mf: float -> unit = <fun>`) is actually the output of the OCaml toplevel interpreter. And it consists of three parts (I use capital letter to denote that this is a variable part of the pattern):

```
val NAME : TYPE = VALUE
```

where `NAME` is a name of a value (in your case it is `mf`), `TYPE` is its inferred type (`float -> unit` in your case), and `VALUE` is a printable representation of the value. Since functions doesn't have a printable representation it is denoted as `<fun>` in your case. You can compare the type of your definition with the type of required definition (i.e., `float -> ins`). It isn't very hard to guess that this types can be equal if type `ins` is equal to type `unit`. Whether it is true depends on your implementation.

I hope, that this will help you. But this is not instead of reading textbooks. I'm just trying to give you starting hints.